# Как сгенерировать SSH ключи для деплоя на GitLab?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-key, gitlab-ci

Сгенерировал SSH ключи, добавил в Secret Variables и Deploy key, сделал конфиг по [примеру](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/deployment/composer-npm-deploy.html#how-to-transfer-files-to-a-live-server), а он падает с ошибкой

```
Host key verification failed.
```

Шаги которые делал:

1. сгенерировал на сервере КУДА буду деплоить, и от пользователя
   который будет деплоить ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Добавил публичный ключ из п.1 в Deploy Keys репозитория с
   отмеченной галочкой Write access allowed
3. Добавил Закрытый ключ (Private key) в Secret variables
   репозитория в переменную SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
4. Конфиг для тестирования подключения

   ```
   image: php:7.0

   before_script:
     - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
     - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
     - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
     - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
     - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
   stage_deploy:
     only:
       - dev
     script:
       - ssh $SSH_SERVER_USER@$SSH_SERVER
   ```

Comment: Предположу что проблема в 4 строке в секции before_script: скорее все в вашем образе не находится файл /.dockerenv и поэтому не выполняется вторая часть строки где отключается запрос на доверие ключам. Выход - попробуйте сокртатить строку до такой: 'echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config' и проверьте запуск, потом уже разберитесь куда делся /.dockerenv

Comment: @СергейГамов заменил. теперь ошибка Permission denied (publickey,password), хотя очень странно что просит пароль, т.к. я создавал ключ без парольной фразы

Comment: Запрос пароля происходит потому что ключ не подошел и следующим вариантом выбирается вход по паролю. Попробуйте этим ключем зайти по ssh не в образе (к примеру со своей машины). ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ) Ключ (публичная часть) должна лежать на сервере в домашней директории пользователя в файле authorized_keys (~/.ssh/authorized_keys)

Comment: @СергейГамов нашел в чем была проблема. не добавил в ~/.ssh/authorized_keys